# Send Task Overdue email 2 days before the due date of the task SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, list, designer-workflow

I have created assign a task Workflow action where i have set expireddate calculated column to assign a value to createddate+7 to due date column. So now due date is set to 7 days after that task has been created.

What i want to do is if user hasnt responded to the task, i want to send out an overdue alert to the assigned user 2 days after job is created, then wait until 2 days and again send email and at last send one at 6 day.

Now under email options we have 3 columns:

1. Task OverDue: Email Editor
2. Frequency: Now i want to send alert to users 2 days
3. Recurrance:

   How do i make that happen using OOTB Assign a task workflow action.

Thank You